# Maven Download old Jars

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am beginning  to use Maven, but i got stuck with it
I am using Eclipse/Win7 64bits

I installed the latest version (3.3.9), created a Maven Project, created a sample class, and went ahead to actually  try to use Maven, downloading the Junit jars from it. When i type junit on the dependencies tab of the pom.xml file, i only get a very old version of junit.
and i have no clue why. after downloading it, i am not able to import anything from said jar. here is the result i get from the search:[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U278J.png)
any idea?
thanks and sorry for anything.

Comment: isn't junit bundled together when you create a simple webapp with maven

Comment: http://search.maven.org/ use this site to search for junit and get the correct dependency.

Comment: You entered `3.8.2` as your version, and seem to have got what you asked for. Just enter a modern version, like `4.12` ans use it. Additionally, unless you're actually developing some tool/extension to work with JUnit, the scope should probably be `test`.

Comment: junit's `groupId` is identified by `org.junit`, not `junit` only.

Comment: The dependency is ok, but too old. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/3.8.2

Do you have a parent-pom or a setting.xml, which defines a company repository or a dependency management section?